# what will be the variance of the random variable s?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Six identical fair dice are thrown independently . Let $s$ denote the number of dice showing even numbers on their upper faces. Then the variance of the random variable $s$ is?

I have seen similar questions on community & other websites but I am unable to get answer for this question. I am making probability distribution taking probabilities $\frac16$ for $X=\{2,4,6\}$ then summation $px = \frac26+\frac46+\frac66=2$ .......... and variance $\frac46+\frac{16}{6}+\frac{36}{6} = \frac{56}{6}$ but unfortunately my answer is wrong .

Comment: This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Please don't use (self-learning) tag just because you were self-studying. This tag is only for questions *about the process of self-studying*. More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(autocomment)*

Comment: does this follow binomial then by npq=6*1/2*1/2= 3/2 ? i am not sure .

Comment: yes the binomial comment is correct

Comment: @BGM thanks , but what is wrong in previous method & where is fault ?

Comment: The random variable $S$ is counting the number of dice having even values. The calculation in the original post seems calculating the expected value $E[X]$ of a single dice roll, and the $E[X^2]$, intersecting with the event that the value is even.

Comment: then what should I do for multiple dice ( for other questions ) by previous method .

Comment: What do you mean by "what should I do for multiple dice  ( for other questions )"? Can you be specific?

Comment: if there are 8 or nine dice ... & I am asking solution by mehod given in original post . listing approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have six die, and the probability of an even number on each die is $3/6=1/2$. If $S$ is the random variable counting the number of even die, then $S$ follows the binomial distribution with $p=1/2$ and $n=6$. The variance is then $np(1-p)=3/2$.

Comment: @alex.r please visit this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188883/what-is-the-value-of-es